# BlueZ scotest App and with Linux Config Can't Connect to SCO Socket

Tags: linux, bluetooth, linux-kernel, kernel, bluez

I am using BlueZ 4.101 on an embedded Linux project with Kernel 3.4.79+. Normal Bluetooth operations work great and I can use many headset with my device to transfer Audio. Now I am working towards Bluetooth Compliance and so I am using the Bluetooth SIG's USB PTS Dongle. I am passing every test except for part of the incoming call test where I need to open the SCO connection after accepting a call with the PTS dongle.

The SCO connection attempt works with the headsets but not with the PTS dongle. The error is given from bluetoothd as:

```
bluetoothd[6306]: audio/headset.c:headset_set_state() State changed /org/bluez/6306/hci0/dev_00_1B_DC_07_30_40: HEADSET_STATE_PLAY_IN_PROGRESS -> HEADSET_STATE_CONNECTED
bluetoothd[6306]: audio/headset.c:headset_set_state() State changed /org/bluez/6306/hci0/dev_00_1B_DC_07_30_40: HEADSET_STATE_CONNECTED -> HEADSET_STATE_PLAY_IN_PROGRESS
bluetoothd[6306]: Protocol not supported (93)
```

So I compiled scotest from the test directory of BlueZ and ran that after connecting with the dongle and got the same result:

```
# ./scotest -s -b HELLO 00:1B:DC:07:30:40
scotest[1687]: Can't connect: Protocol not supported (93)
scotest[1687]: Can't connect to the server: Protocol not supported (93)
```

Here is the do_connect function in scotest.c that is failing in:

```
static int do_connect(char *svr)
{
    struct sockaddr_sco addr;
    struct sco_conninfo conn;
    socklen_t optlen;
    int sk;

    /* Create socket */
    sk = socket(PF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_SEQPACKET, BTPROTO_SCO);
    if (sk < 0) {
        syslog(LOG_ERR, "Can't create socket: %s (%d)",
                            strerror(errno), errno);
        return -1;
    }

    /* Bind to local address */
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sco_family = AF_BLUETOOTH;
    bacpy(&addr.sco_bdaddr, &bdaddr);

    if (bind(sk, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0) {
        syslog(LOG_ERR, "Can't bind socket: %s (%d)",
                            strerror(errno), errno);
        goto error;
    }

    /* Connect to remote device */
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sco_family = AF_BLUETOOTH;
    str2ba(svr, &addr.sco_bdaddr);

    if (connect(sk, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0) {
        syslog(LOG_ERR, "Can't connect: %s (%d)",
                            strerror(errno), errno);
        goto error;
    }

    /* Get connection information */
    memset(&conn, 0, sizeof(conn));
    optlen = sizeof(conn);

    if (getsockopt(sk, SOL_SCO, SCO_CONNINFO, &conn, &optlen) < 0) {
        syslog(LOG_ERR, "Can't get SCO connection information: %s (%d)",
                            strerror(errno), errno);
        goto error;
    }

    syslog(LOG_INFO, "Connected [handle %d, class 0x%02x%02x%02x]",
        conn.hci_handle,
        conn.dev_class[2], conn.dev_class[1], conn.dev_class[0]);

    return sk;

error:
    close(sk);
    return -1;
}
```

What am I missing in the Kernel Config to allow the PTS dongle to be put into a Playing state with an open SCO connection?

Here is my .config for Linux ( I'm using backports-3.13.2-1 to support the TI WL1271 BT/WiFi module ):

```
CPTCFG_IPV6_SUBTREES=y
CPTCFG_NFT_RBTREE=m
CPTCFG_BRIDGE_NF_EBTABLES=m
CPTCFG_BRIDGE_EBT_BROUTE=m
CPTCFG_BRIDGE_EBT_T_FILTER=m
CPTCFG_BRIDGE_EBT_T_NAT=m
CPTCFG_BRIDGE_EBT_802_3=m
CPTCFG_BRIDGE_EBT_AMONG=m
CPTCFG_BRIDGE_EBT_ARP=m
CPTCFG_BRIDGE_EBT_IP=m
CPTCFG_BRIDGE_EBT_IP6=m
CPTCFG_BRIDGE_EBT_LIMIT=m
CPTCFG_BRIDGE_EBT_MARK=m
CPTCFG_BRIDGE_EBT_PKTTYPE=m
CPTCFG_BRIDGE_EBT_STP=m
CPTCFG_BRIDGE_EBT_VLAN=m
CPTCFG_BRIDGE_EBT_ARPREPLY=m
CPTCFG_BRIDGE_EBT_DNAT=m
CPTCFG_BRIDGE_EBT_MARK_T=m
CPTCFG_BRIDGE_EBT_REDIRECT=m
CPTCFG_BRIDGE_EBT_SNAT=m
CPTCFG_BRIDGE_EBT_LOG=m
CPTCFG_BRIDGE_EBT_NFLOG=m
CPTCFG_MAC_EMUMOUSEBTN=m
CPTCFG_RTLBTCOEXIST=m
CPTCFG_TABLET_USB_KBTAB=m
CPTCFG_INPUT_ATLAS_BTNS=m
CPTCFG_SND_BT87X=m
CPTCFG_LIRC_BT829=m
CPTCFG_USB_BTMTK=m
CPTCFG_TOSHIBA_BT_RFKILL=m
CPTCFG_BTRFS_FS=m
CPTCFG_BTRFS_FS_POSIX_ACL=y
CPTCFG_RBTREE_TEST=m
CPTCFG_ASYMMETRIC_PUBLIC_KEY_SUBTYPE=y
CPTCFG_BTREE=y
CPTCFG_BACKPORT_OPTION_BT_SOCK_CREATE_NEEDS_KERN=y
CPTCFG_BT=m
CPTCFG_BT_RFCOMM=m
# CPTCFG_BT_RFCOMM_TTY is not set
CPTCFG_BT_BNEP=m
CPTCFG_BT_BNEP_MC_FILTER=y
CPTCFG_BT_BNEP_PROTO_FILTER=y
# CPTCFG_BT_CMTP is not set
CPTCFG_BT_HIDP=m
CPTCFG_BT_HCIBTUSB=m
CPTCFG_BT_HCIBTSDIO=m
CPTCFG_BT_HCIUART=m
CPTCFG_BT_HCIUART_H4=y
CPTCFG_BT_HCIUART_BCSP=y
# CPTCFG_BT_HCIUART_ATH3K is not set
CPTCFG_BT_HCIUART_LL=y
CPTCFG_BT_HCIUART_3WIRE=y
# CPTCFG_BT_HCIBCM203X is not set
# CPTCFG_BT_HCIBPA10X is not set
# CPTCFG_BT_HCIBFUSB is not set
# CPTCFG_BT_HCIDTL1 is not set
# CPTCFG_BT_HCIBT3C is not set
# CPTCFG_BT_HCIBLUECARD is not set
CPTCFG_BT_HCIBTUART=m
CPTCFG_BT_HCIVHCI=m
# CPTCFG_BT_MRVL is not set
# CPTCFG_BT_ATH3K is not set
CPTCFG_BT_WILINK=m
```

I instrumented the sco.c file in the kernel with printks.

On success with a normal headset it looks like this after successfully opening SCO connection:

```
*** sco_sock_create
*** sco_sock_alloc
*** sco_sock_init
*** sco_sock_bind
*** sco_sock_connect
*** sco_connect
*** sco_conn_add
*** sco_chan_add
*** __sco_chan_add
*** sco_sock_set_timer
*** sco_connect_cfm
*** sco_conn_add
*** sco_conn_ready
*** sco_sock_clear_timer
*** sco_sock_getsockopt
*** sco_sock_setsockopt_old
*** sco_sock_getsockopt
*** sco_sock_setsockopt_old
*** sco_sock_sendmsg
*** sco_send_frame
*** sco_sock_sendmsg
*** sco_send_frame
*** sco_sock_sendmsg
*** sco_send_frame
```

On failure it looks like this:

```
*** sco_sock_create
*** sco_sock_alloc
*** sco_sock_init
*** sco_sock_bind
*** sco_sock_connect
*** sco_connect
*** sco_conn_add
*** sco_chan_add
*** __sco_chan_add
*** sco_sock_set_timer
*** sco_connect_cfm
*** sco_conn_del
*** sco_chan_get
*** sco_sock_clear_timer
*** sco_chan_del
*** sco_sock_release
*** sco_sock_close
*** sco_sock_kill
*** sco_sock_clear_timer
*** __sco_sock_connect
*** sco_sock_kill
*** sco_sock_kill
*** sco_sock_destruct
```

Further instrumentation shows the failures are happening in this sco.c function:

```
void sco_connect_cfm(struct hci_conn *hcon, __u8 status)
{

    printk("*** sco_connect_cfm start\n");

    BT_DBG("hcon %p bdaddr %pMR status %d", hcon, &hcon->dst, status);
    printk("*** sco_connect_cfm_stat hcon %p bdaddr %pMR status %d\n", hcon, &hcon->dst, status);
    if (!status) {
        struct sco_conn *conn;

        conn = sco_conn_add(hcon);
        printk("*** sco_connect_cfm sco_conn_add: %d\n",conn);
        if (conn)
            printk("*** sco_connect_cfm ready\n");
            sco_conn_ready(conn);
    } else
        printk("*** sco_connect_delete: %d\n",status);
        sco_conn_del(hcon, bt_to_errno(status));
}
```

That output looks like this:

```
*** sco_sock_create
*** sco_sock_alloc
*** sco_sock_init
*** sco_sock_bind
*** sco_sock_connect
*** sco_connect
*** sco_conn_add
*** sco_chan_add
*** __sco_chan_add
*** sco_sock_set_timer
*** sco_connect_cfm start
*** sco_connect_cfm_stat hcon d9ec2400 bdaddr 40:30:07:dc:1b:00 status 26
*** sco_connect_delete: 26
*** sco_conn_del
*** sco_chan_get
*** sco_sock_clear_timer
*** sco_chan_del
*** sco_sock_release
*** sco_sock_close
*** sco_sock_clear_timer
*** sco_sock_kill
*** __sco_sock_connect
*** sco_sock_kill
*** sco_sock_kill
*** sco_sock_destruct
```

Comment: can you print bluetooth related stuff from your .config file here?

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. I've added my .config to the question.

Comment: are you sure all the bluetooth stuff is enabled?

Comment: Yes I've turned on everything except for bluetooth drivers for chips that I don't have on the board. It works great with every headset I've tried but not the SIG PTS dongle. It can create and bind to the SCO socket but fails in the 'connect' with Protocol Not Supported ( 93 )

Comment: may be my stupid doubt but is it needed to do bind() on client side?

Comment: I know it's old but... maybe someone will read it and find it useful. You only bind on server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not the configuration of the Kernel but rather the set of drivers I was using. I had compiled the linux backports ( http://drvbp1.linux-foundation.org/~mcgrof/rel-html/backports/) version of the bluetooth drivers, because I needed the backported wifi drivers, and that gave me the Protocol Not Supported (93) error. I switched back to the drivers distributed with the Kernel 3.4.79+ and it worked.